# Cpu vs gpu vs ram rendering in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, performance

I have an Intel Core2Duo e7400 processor, 3 GB ram, 120G SSD hard drive, and an nVidia Geforce 750Ti 2GB graphics card. When i gpu render vast scenes of about 100MB using Cycles in Blender, I receive the CUDA out of memory error. My motherboard maximum ram support is only 4gb DDR2.

So i wants to ask if I should buy an AMD RX480 8GB graphics card, or alternatively an i7 6700k processor with 16GB RAM to work with my 750Ti graphics card. Which one will be better for rendering large images and animations?

Comment: If you have a choice, think twice about AMD card, support for them in blender has been problematic. Nvidia cards have better support

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the hardware blender runs on, and not about a problem within blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, everything depends on your scene.

An 8GB graphics cards will be faster than than your CPU but you will be limited to 8GB (side note: do not keep in your old 2GB graphics card, along with the new 8GB card, Blender will only use the ram of the lowest card)

If you go with the CPU 16GB ram then you will be able to render larger scenes but it will be slower.

I would say get the graphics card with 8GB.

Comment: When i load my blender scene 2.5gb ram is used only 500mb ram remain and when i render it crashes my blender also and i cant animate a simple monkey suzzaine. Is that problem of my geforce 750ti graphics card or my old core2 duo pc with 3gb ram?

Comment: When your computer freezes/crashes is the GPU rendering the scene or is the CPU? Actually this is a tough one, I guess I would change my answer, go with the i7 processer with 16gb ram so you dont run into memory problems and then when you get more money I would get the graphics cards also. Really you need both so go with the i7 then in the future get the graphics card.